# Set date and time in java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp, java-time

Please tell me how to set the date (current date minus one day) and time equal to 19:00:00 using such a construction?

```
new java.sql.Timestamp(java.util.Calendar.getInstance.getTime().getTime())
```

LocalDateTime don't use.

Comment: _LocalDateTime don't use_ Do you mean that you can't use the [date-time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Timestamp` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. If your SQL datatype is `timestamp with time zone` (recommended for the majority of purposes), use `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). If it is `timestamp` (without time zone) or `datetime`, do use `LocalDateTime` from the same API. Why not?

Comment: Or to put it the other way around: Like you said, don’t use `LocalDateTime` for a timestamp. Use `OffsetDateTime` or `Instant`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you do it using the `java.time` (the modern date-time API).

### Solution, purely using the modern API:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                                .minusDays(1)
                                .with(LocalTime.of(19, 0))
                                .toOffsetDateTime();

        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-24T19:00Z
```

You can use the `OffsetDateTime` in your JDBC code as follows:

```
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (columnfoo) VALUES (?)");
st.setObject(1, odt);
st.executeUpdate();
st.close();
```

However, if you still want to use `java.sql.Timestamp`, you can use `ZonedDateTime` with the applicable timezone to get the required date-time and then convert it into `Instant` from which you can get Epoch milliseconds. You can Finally use the Epoch milliseconds to construct an instance of `java.sql.Timestamp`.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                            .minusDays(1)
                            .with(LocalTime.of(19, 0));
        
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
        System.out.println(timestamp);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-24 19:00:00.0
```

**Notes:**

1. I have used `ZoneId.systemDefault()` which uses the JVM's timezone. Change it to applicable timezone e.g. `ZoneId.of("Europe/London")`.
2. `Instant` belongs to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.
3. For whatsoever reason if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

### Solution, purely using the legacy API:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 19);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
        System.out.println(timestamp);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-12-24 19:00:00.0
```

Comment: — And while this answer is helpful in the best of ways by showing a better alternative to the `Timestamp` class, it *also* does answer the question as asked: how to set a `java.sql.Timestamp` to yesterday at 19.

Comment: Thanks, @OleV.V. for approving the answer. It's the positive feedback on the correct usage of the modern date-time API and helpful comments, from the date-time champions like [Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/users/642706/basil-bourque) and you, that has encouraged many, like me, to learn and explore deeper the modern date-time API.

Comment: Actually, I do see a problem with this Answer. The first solution should replace `OffsetDateTime.now` with `ZonedDateTime.now`. Then later in the code convert to an `OffsetDateTime` for use with JDBC 4.2. The current code fails on any days where the politicians in that region are changing the offset of their time zone, such as cut-over for Daylight Saving Time (DST) or a [diplomatic move between North Korea – South Korea](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-44010705).

Comment: @BasilBourque - Thank you. I have replaced `OffsetDateTime.now` with `ZonedDateTime.now`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code

Set date to yesterday with `Calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1)`

Compare hour with `Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)`

`getHour` of java.sql.Timestamp is Deprecated.

*replaced by `Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)`.*

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Calendar;

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // 2020-12-25 19:42:57.739
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

System.out.println(timestamp); // 2020-12-24 19:42:57.739
System.out.println(19 == calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)); // true
```

Bye!

Comment: These are terrible legacy classes. See modern *java.time* solution in [answer by Live and Let Live](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65447424/642706).